# Importing ScrollView module disables fullscreen mode in kivy

Tags: kivy

Including the line, `from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView` nullifies the effect of `Config.set('graphics', 'fullscreen', '1')`, such that when ScrollView is imported, the application becomes windowed rather than full-screen. How can I full-screen my application while utilizing ScrollView? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you need define your configuration first. Compare:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import kivy
kivy.require('1.7.1')

from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('graphics', 'fullscreen', 'auto')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView 

class ImageApp(App):
    def build(self):
        layout = BoxLayout()
        button = Button(text="Exit", size_hint=(None, None))
        layout.add_widget(button)
        button.bind(on_press=exit)
        return layout

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ImageApp().run()
```

With:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import kivy
kivy.require('1.7.1')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView 

from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('graphics', 'fullscreen', 'auto')

class ImageApp(App):
    def build(self):
        layout = BoxLayout()
        button = Button(text="Exit", size_hint=(None, None))
        layout.add_widget(button)
        button.bind(on_press=exit)
        return layout

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ImageApp().run()
```

**UPDATE**

Let's try to look at this behaviour. In the `ScrollView` module there is a `kivy.metrics.sp` used for calculating scrolling distance. So actually this code won't get us full screen either:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import kivy
kivy.require('1.7.1')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button

from kivy.metrics import sp
val = sp(1)

from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('graphics', 'fullscreen', 'auto')

class ImageApp(App):
    def build(self):
        layout = BoxLayout()
        button = Button(text="Exit", size_hint=(None, None))
        layout.add_widget(button)
        button.bind(on_press=exit)
        return layout

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ImageApp().run()
```

`kivy.metrics.sp` have following definition:

```
from kivy.properties import dpi2px
def sp(value):
    return dpi2px(value, 'sp')
```

It's calling `kivy.properties.dpi2px` which, as name suggests, converting dpi to pixels, so it need to have screen dpi calculated. Looks like the culprit is here.

Comment: Yep, the ordering took care of it. Thanks! Can you elaborate a bit on why precedence matters in this scenario?

Comment: @James_L, I expanded my answer.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, it's easiest to import Config from kivy.config first, and do your config changes, before importing anything else from kivy, this way you take no risk that something create the root window before your configuration are applied.